# c++ manage multiples data types homogenous

Tags: c++, templates

hi i am develop a class that manage multiples data types, by so i have created a class wrapper that can contain a diverse types of data, but a im stuck with a compiler issue:

```
class BaseType{
public:
    virtual ~BaseType(){}
    virtual BaseType & clone() const =0;
};

template<typename T>
class DataType : public BaseType
{
public:
    DataType(const T & aValueData = T()):mValue(aValueData) {}

    BaseType & clone() const
    {
        return DataType<T>();
    }
private:
    T mValue;
};

class MValueData
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    MValueData(T & aAnyValue = DataType(aAnyValue)):mTypeData(aAnyValue)
    {}
private:
    BaseType mTypeData;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This code generate the following compiler error:

```
error: cannot declare field 'MValueData::mTypeData' to be of abstract type 'BaseType'
```

the mTypeData menber variable is declared as it, but it is derived from basetype, i dont see the error.
Thx in advance

Comment: This problem may already be solved for you, take a look at boost.any http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/any.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your base class was not abstract, you'd still be facing the slicing problem.

see e.g. [this answer describing what that means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274634/2513200)

So, you need to store a `BaseType` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a variable that's type is abstract. Since BaseType is abstract (it has a pure virtual function `BaseType::clone`) you cannot declare a variable of that type. You can either store a reference to BaseType or a pointer to BaseType, but not a BaseType.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store `mTypeData` as a `BaseType` by value, this will remove all reference to it being a `DataType`; this means you'll have an instance of an abstract class, which isn't allowed.

If you wish to store a child class as its parent, you need to store it as a `BaseType*` and then instantiate it with `new DataType(aAnyValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have object of BaseType, because it is an abstract class.